# My procedures update statement is leaving a null value in my table

Tags: sql, function, plsql, procedure

I am trying to write a function that retrieves the number of hours that a user defined consultant has been assigned to a user defined project and the value should be returned to the plsql anonymous block calling the function. My procedure should update the number of hours that the consultant has been assigned to the project.

**UPDATE:** ok so I edited my code and finally got the function to return the correct value. Now all I need is to call my procedure to actually update the tables. The **IF statement in my anonymous block doesnt seem to recognize the newtotal_hours**. Any ideas???

**NEW UPDATE** ok so I got everything compiling and returning as it should be however the only problem I have left is that **my procedure's update statement is causing a null value in the table where the updated newtotal_hours should replace it** how can I fix this???

Here is my table:

```
project_consultant
(p_id number(6),
c_id  number(6),
total_hours number(6)
);
```

and here is my **WORKING UPDATED FUNCTION:**

```
create or replace function return_num_hours (pid number, cid number)
return number is
totalhrs        project_consultant.total_hours%type;
cursor c1 is select total_hours from project_consultant where p_id=pid and c_id=cid;

begin
    open c1;
    fetch c1 into totalhrs;
    close c1;
    return totalhrs;
end;
/
```

and finally heres my procedure:

```
create or replace procedure update_hours (proj_id number, consult_id number) is

change_in_hours     number(6);
project_id      project_consultant.p_id%type;
consultant_id       project_consultant.c_id%type;
totalhours      project_consultant.total_hours%type;

cursor c2 is select p_id, c_id, total_hours from project_consultant where p_id=proj_id and 

c_id=consult_id;
begin
    open c2;
    fetch c2 into project_id, consultant_id, totalhours;

    totalhours := totalhours + change_in_hours;
    update project_consultant set total_hours = totalhours  where p_id = proj_id and c_id = consult_id;
    --commit;

    close c2;


end;
/
```

my user-defined anonymous block to call the function and procedure..

```
declare
    totalnumhours   number(6);
    change_in_hours number(6);
    newtotal_hours  number(6);
    project_id  number(6);
    consultant_id   number(6);

begin
    consultant_id   := &consult_id;
    project_id  := &proj_id;
    change_in_hours := &change_in_hours;

    totalnumhours := return_num_hours(project_id, consultant_id);
    dbms_output.put_line(totalnumhours);
    newtotal_hours := totalnumhours + change_in_hours;
    dbms_output.put_line(newtotal_hours);




    if newtotal_hours > 0 then
    update_hours(project_id, consultant_id);
    dbms_output.put_line('Consultant ' ||consultant_id||' Project '||project_id||':'||' changed planned hours from '||totalnumhours||' 

to '||newtotal_hours);
    else
    dbms_output.put_line('Cannot update number of hours to a negative total');
    end if;
    commit;
exception
    when no_data_found then
    dbms_output.put_line('No such consultant or project');

end;
/
```

script output for consultant_id:101 project_id:1

```
SQL> select * from project_consultant

      P_ID       C_ID TOTAL_HOURS
---------- ---------- -----------
         1        101
         1        104         245
         1        103          50
         1        105          45
         2        105          25
         2        100           0
         3        103         125
         3        104          50
         4        105          25
         4        104         125
         4        102          30

      P_ID       C_ID TOTAL_HOURS
---------- ---------- -----------
         5        105          15
         5        103          15
         6        103           5
         6        104          10
         7        102         125
         7        100         100

17 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function you return third input parameter `totalhours` as a result `return(totalhours);`. Is it ok? I guess that you want to return value of `totalhrs`

Comment: I shall test it and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: hmmm I did that and it didn't work...I did change the parameters to only be (pid, cid) and now I got the function to return a value. I shall update my code so y'all can see.

Comment: please, could you provide script output? what values do you fill variables

Comment: added the output for the script...for my values I did consultant_id: 101 and project_id: 1

Comment: `change_in_hours := &change_in_hours;` what value change_in_hours has?

Comment: i used 20 as my value just to test it...the original value for that particular slot was supposed to be 215 so + 20 the new value should be 235

Comment: in your procedure `create or replace procedure update_hours (proj_id number, consult_id number)` you didn't pass value of `change_in_hours`, it is initialized with null value, any arifmetic operation with null produce null, so in line ` totalhours := totalhours + change_in_hours;` you got null. please try to pass change_in_hourse to your procedure

Comment: do I pass it through the parameters or what do you mean?